# Keys does not match -dkim

Tags: dkim

I installed opendkim on server and have checked on mxtoolbox.com verifier that my dkim is done.
However on using `opendkim-testkey` command i am getting following error:

```
$ opendkim-testkey -v

opendkim-testkey: using default configfile /etc/opendkim.conf
opendkim-testkey: key loaded from /etc/opendkim/keys/jobsinhospitality.in/default.private
opendkim-testkey: checking key 'default._domainkey.jobsinhospitality.in' 
opendkim-testkey: keys do not match

$ dig default._domainkey.jobsinhospitality.in TXT
```

Comment: opendkim-testkey: using default configfile /etc/opendkim.conf
opendkim-testkey: key loaded from /etc/opendkim/keys/jobsinhospitality.in/default.private
opendkim-testkey: checking key 'default._domainkey.jobsinhospitality.in'
opendkim-testkey: keys do not match

Comment: Please clarify in what way *mxtoolbox* lead you to believe dkim is correctly setup, because to me it says the opposite.

Comment: I have changed the selector and now the selector is mg._domainkey.jobsinhospitality.in .MXtoolbar           dkim:jobsinhospitality.in:mg

Comment: I deleted the old selector and created a new one. The selector name is mg . Onrunning dkim lookup on mxtoolbox for jobsinhospitality.in:mg  , I am getting  :v=DKIM1; k=rsa;p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDLon7nCRvs24YYnQDufk+U+wlbJX3CyIdBGZljUSsxBZnubqBL5Dm6vr7yxYgJvLGkJ29dq/GKyguvzikvWCrFZ848acO9qc1T/WU14X9Pu6m+hYQTroAk7cW2cZDc/YtCthHsmAsQYy27C0twH8uJ28wE1n2tOvfjFVijxuvmFQIDAQAB

Answer (score 3):

Your key is now published as `mg._domainkey.jobsinhospitality.in`. However, it appears the text field is too long and may not be parsed correctly.  The TXT data must be broken into text segments of no more than 255 characters.  See [Implement DKIM with Exim](https://www.systemajik.com/blog/implementing-dkim-with-exim/) for a couple of format options for publishing if your DNS server is `bind`.

If your internal DNS configuration is different from the external DNS configuration ensure the public key is published to the external DNS.  You will also need it configured on the internal DNS to test from the command line.